# Merge data from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, both of which have a KEY and a few columns, I'd like to merge them into a single table when the key is the same

e.g: 
Table 1: Key | Attr 1 | Attr 2 | Attr 3

Table 2: Key | Attr 1 | Attr 2 | Attr 4

I'm trying to end up with:
Table 3: Key | Attr 1 | Attr 2 | Attr 3 | Attr 4

I tried using this:

```
SELECT 
  T1.KEY,
  T1.ATTR1,
  T1.ATTR2,
  T1.ATTR3,
  CASE 
    WHEN T1.KEY = T2.KEY
    THEN T2.ATTR4
    ELSE 0
   END AS ATTR4
  FROM TABLE_1 AS T1, TABLE_2 AS T2
```

but for some reason, I get a ton of duplicates

Comment: You need a JOIN condition! E.g. `FROM TABLE_1 AS T1 JOIN TABLE_2 AS T2 ON t1.key = t2.key`.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  And tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What about if you add a distinct?

Comment: I should end up with 18765 rows but for some reason end up with 20426, so I'm not really sure why I'm getting so many duplicates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing that you really want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT T1.*, COALESCE(T2.ATTR4, 0) as ATTR4
FROM TABLE_1 T1 LEFT JOIN
     TABLE_2 AS T2
     ON T1.KEY = T2.KEY
```

Comment: I tried that but ended up with about 3000 duplicate rows for some reason, and I'm not really sure why